# I want to delete all checked item from my monogoDB database on clicking delete button

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I am using EJS view engine don't know how to add logic so that all mongoDB document id get which are checked by user got collected and sent by post request route

[how my to do list look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8VKj.png)

I don't have idea how I can do this

Comment: Hi, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)